# Animate UIView height when using auto layout with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode6

Before Auto-layout, I've been animating a background's height in a project by setting the frame over `animateWithDuration`.

```
func setUpBackground() {
    self.backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 10)
    self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x2d2d2d).CGColor
}

func AnimateBackgroundHeight() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 600)    
    })
}
```

After I converted my project to auto layout, I noticed that the animation occurs but the background height snaps back to the original size/style (interface builder setting) after. I read that when Auto-layout is turned on, the constraints will overwrite setting the `UIView` dimensions with `CGRect`.

Therefore I'm wondering how to go about achieving the same height change animation effect with Auto-layout ON.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Give your backgroundView a height constraint, and make an IBOutlet to it. In code, modify the constraint's constant value.

```
func AnimateBackgroundHeight() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
         self.heightCon.constant = 600 // heightCon is the IBOutlet to the constraint
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    
    })
}
```

Comment: how to get the height during animation of a view?

Answer (score 7):

Also for those of you who find this post trying to figure out why a transition changing a view's size will be blocky or unclean you just need to find the view in charge and call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside of the `UIView.animateWithDuration` block. I was banging my head against the wall trying different things with constraints and making frames until realizing that `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` will handle making the transition smooth as long as you are placing it in the right location.

Comment: Spent 7 hours trying to figure out why my layout was breaking when animating. After seeing you posts I realized I was calling layoutIfNeeded on a subview not the superview. Thanks!!